# Converting a normal list into a nb/spdep object in R?

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp, spdep

I need to create a neighbours list from a spatial polygon. At the moment i am using the function `poly2nb`, but unfortunately it is not very accurate, and some polygons with no common points are considered neighbours. I have tried changing the `snap` argument, but with no luck.
I have however tried the function `gTouches` from the `rgeos` package, and it works much better. Only problem is, it creates a `list` object that cannot be used in `spdep`. Is there any way to convert it into a `nb` object?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code for the `tri2nb` function https://rdrr.io/cran/spdep/src/R/tri2nb.R, which I know is a different function than the one you mentioned, you can change the `list` to `nb` type:

`class(yourlist) <- "nb"`

An example:

```
mylist <- list(A = c(1,2,5,6), B = c(2,4,6,5))
class(mylist) #check the class of mylist
```

Initial Result:

```
> class(mylist)
[1] "list"
```

Assign the class of mylist as nb

```
class(mylist) <- "nb"
class(mylist) #check the class of mylist
```

Final Result:

```
> class(mylist)
[1] "nb"
```

From this, you can continue to use functions in `spdep` to select optimal spatial weighting matrices.

Comment: Yes, this is all that you need to do. There are some checks that the print method utilize that may cause an error if you made an incompatible list. If you want the nb list to be compatible with dplyr be sure to keep the list class too. e.g `class(mylist) <- c("nb", "list")`